# Load nested resource properties values in edit inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, api-platform.com

**I'm using React Admin to generate CRUDs for my API.**

In my API, I have an resource Person which contains a nested resource Profile on a one-to-one relation.
When creating and editing a person, my API allows to directly send the properties of the profile, and create or edit the nested Profile resource.

This is what I receive when I do a `GET` on a person, and it's also what I can send to my API when I do a `PUT` or `POST`

```
person: {
    profile: {
        firstName,
        lastName
   },
   ...otherPersonProperties
}
```

On the Edit page of the resource Person, I display the input fields relative to the profile nested resource :

```
<Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
       <TextInput source="profile.firstName" {...props} />
       <TextInput source="profile.lastName" {...props} />
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

I would have expected the text inputs relative to the nested resource Profile to be pre-filled with fetched values but the inputs are empty.

Is it not possible to load values of a nested resource properties into a TextInput ?

**EDIT**

This is what the fetch gets me :

```
@context: "/api/contexts/Person"
@id: "/api/persons/1004"
@type: "Person"
user: "/api/users/28"
profile: {
    @id: "/api/profiles/1004"
    @type: "Profile"
    firstName: "trainee2_firstName"
    lastName: "trainee2_lastname"
}
```

But this is what's inside formData :

```
@context: "/api/contexts/Person"
@id: "/api/persons/1002"
@type: "Person"
id: "/api/persons/1002"
user: "/api/users/28"
profile: "/api/profiles/1002"
```

It seems that React Admin doesn't understand that I want the profile fields values to be injected in the form.

Comment: `source="profile.firstName"` is just passing a string, `source={person.profile.firstName}` should work. Im still missing context to be sure whats wrong/missing. And if its a input, its probably `value={person.profile.firstName}`

Comment: I should have made it clearer that I'm talking about the library React Admin. It definitely expects a string as a source for its input and field : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html

Comment: Are you receiving the expected data from your `GET` request? Can you show us the request response? Because it should work they way you have implemented it.

Comment: @ThomasVangelooven I updated my question to show the result of my fetch vs the result of the property formData. The problem definitely comes from the fact that React Admin knows that profile is a reference and doesn't inject the fetched nested properties values into the form.